# Review contract function response by block number

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ether, ethers.js

I am looking way to create a report on how specific function responses change block by block.

Something like:

```
   const responses = []

   
   for(let i = 0; i < blockNumberList.length; i++){
     const blockNumber = blockNumberList[i]
     const response = await contract.foo() // <-- should return response by block number
     responses.push(response)
   }
```

What I do now:

I have hardhat project with config like:

```
hardhat: {
  forking: {
    url: ''https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/key',
      blockNumber: 13413700,
    },
},
```

and function call like:

```
  const response = contract.func()
```

If I change manually blocknumber and restart harhad console, I get different responses by blocknumber.

I am looking more efficient way to collect responses than collect then manually changing config.

Comment: I do not understand. A transaction cannot know in which block it will be included and you cannot force a transaction to be included into a specific block. So what are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: @Itération122442 Look I updated the question, I tried explaining how I deal with it now.

Answer (score 0):

For view functions, ethers.js allow a [blockTag](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/ab319f2f4c365d4cd1b1e17e577ecd18a7a89276/packages/contracts/src.ts/index.ts#L33) override.

```
for(let i = 0; i < blockNumberList.length; i++){
  const blockNumber = blockNumberList[i]
  const response = await contract.foo({
    blockTag: blockNumber
  })
}
```

For this, you need an archive node (I think you already have that arranged since you are using hardhat mainnet fork, but just mentioning here).

Some backends who are not archive nodes, they silently ignore the `blockTag` and give you state for latest block, you may have to watch out for that as well :P

Comment: no need to use archive nodes if using web3.js,  ethers.js quite weird

Comment: I tried that with this function:  
```
const generateContractFunctionList = tokens =>
  tokens.map(({ address: tokenAddress, symbol }) =>
    contract(symbol, abi, tokenAddress).balanceOf(walletAddress, {blockTag: blockNumber}),
);
```  

But I got this error `Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":1,"values":2}, value={"types":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address","indexed":null,"components":null,"arrayLength":null,"arrayChildren":null,"baseType":"address","_isParamType":true}],"values":["<myaddress>",{"blockTag":"12155258"}]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)`